# Install OpenCV correctly on macOS Sierra

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, macos-sierra

I am running on macOS Sierra and I have python 3.5.2 installed on my system. 
Now I want to use opencv with python. So here is what I did :-

1. Installed XCode
2. Installed CMAKE
3. Downloaded opencv 3.2 and extracted to my Document directory.
4. Created a new directory called build inside my opencv directory in Document (obtained from step 3)
5. Opened CMAKE and configured it to run with source as the opencv directory in Document and target as the build directory within it.
6. Ran the "make" command from "build" directory
7. Ran "sudo make install"

All these steps completed successfully. Now I go to IDLE 3.5.2 shell and do "import cv2" and then I get the error "ImportError: No module named cv2"

I tried other solutions like pip3 install opencv-python. It removes the import error but I cannot use this because it doesn't support cv2.imshow() (I kind of need it).

Please help me install and configure opencv correctly.

Comment: 1) Did you run `xcode-select --install` afterwards? 2) How? 5) Did you run `cmake`? If so, how exactly?

Comment: No i didn't run xcode-select --install. When should I have done this (after which step) ? Well for CMAKE i installed the application from cmake.org and ran (launched it). Once cmake generated the files, I opened terminal and navigated the directory where the generated files were placed ("build" directory in my case) and executed the command "make". Once make completed, i ran "sudo make install" from the same terminal window.

Comment: The `xcode-select --install` should be after 1) that's why I labelled it like that:-)

Comment: What switches did you use with `cmake` when you ran it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell : Thank you clarifying. By "switches" do you mean the "generator for the project" which `cmake` application prompted me to choose ? I went ahead with "Unix makefiles".

Comment: No, I was asking *how* you ran `cmake`. Did you run `cmake -Dxyz=abc ..` or what exactly.

Comment: @Mark I assume the OP used GUI Cmake App. @Shiv: make sure to use the latest Cmake (3.8.x), it helps finding python correctly. Once you press configure on Cmake, try to look for `python3`  in the log. If it's in `To be built`, then it should be installed. Otherwise, you would need to config `python3` manually in Cmake.

Comment: On other note, you can check in the `build/lib/python3/` if there is a `cv2.*.so`. It so, symlink it to python3's `site_packages` folder would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck you can try by brew, did a fresh install some weeks ago and here is the full process.
As opencv cant support python2 & 3 by default install (read further)

```
brew edit opencv3
```

in formula edit this part:

```
if build.with?("python3") && build.with?("python")
  # Opencv3 Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 versions
odie "opencv3: Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 wrappers"
end
```

by commenting it out ( # at start line).

then:
    brew reinstall opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --HEAD

if you have cmake.downloader error you need to edit the brew call and remove the --HEAD flag.
This error is just du to a file missing in the head repository (might be fix soon or not).

Also check your site-package/python version

Answer (score 0):

One issue I found was with then name of the .so library created on install. Try renaming it to cv2.so instead of the longer name it starts with.

On my system it's found here:

```
/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Also, you can confirm that the above site-packages folder is accessible via sys.path.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

If not, you can create a .pth file in one of those directories that contains simply the path name of your site-packages folder above.